# Alias import undefined in Angular 7 production moe

Tags: angular, production

Hye guys!
When using alias on import and build the project in production mode (--prod flag),
The alias is undefined.
This behavior doesn't happened in development mode.

Any idea?

Example:

```
import { Utils as UtilBox } from '../../utils';
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for production is `import * as utilbox from '../../utils'`. This is a **non-relative** import, as specified [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: Prod mode in angular 4/5 was ok with this importa, why?

Comment: Btw, I don't want to import a whole file that I don't need

Comment: Try without brackets then. Some concepts about Module Resolution change for each Typescript releases.

Comment: You can't import and alias without brackets